# How can I use SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT with a Cache-Control header?

Tags: django

I've enabled `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` in the settings of my django deployment, so now these headers are getting sent to the client:

```
< HTTP/1.1 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
< Date: Fri, 19 Feb 2016 15:57:50 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
< Location: https://www.example.com/
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

The main disadvantage with 301 redirects is that they tend to be cached for a very long time by browsers, so I would quite like to add a `Cache-Control: max-age=604800, must-revalidate` header to this. Preferably, I would like a way that doesn't involve re-implementing `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try overriding Django's `SecurityMiddleware` to add the http headers you need. Below is a full implementation of the middleware:

```
class CustomSecurityMiddleware(SecurityMiddleware):

    def process_request(self, request):
        response = super(CustomSecurityMiddleware, self).process_request(request)

        # SecurityMiddleware returns an HttpResponsePermanentRedirect only if 
        # the request should be redirected
        if response is not None:
            response['Cache-Control'] = 'max-age=604800, must-revalidate'
            return response
```

This implementation retains everything that Django's `SecurityMiddleware` does already, while adding the custom http headers you need.

The custom middleware should replace SecurityMiddleware in `settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.